# split login session into shift buckets

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, time-series

I have a table of logins and logouts by user.

the table looks like this but has a few hundred thousand rows:

```
data = [['aa', '2020-05-31 00:00:01', '2020-05-31 00:00:31'],
        ['bb','2020-05-31 00:01:01', '2020-05-31 00:02:01'],
        ['aa','2020-05-31 00:02:01', '2020-05-31 00:06:03'],
        ['cc','2020-05-31 00:03:01', '2020-05-31 00:04:01'],
        ['dd','2020-05-31 00:04:01', '2020-05-31 00:34:01'],
        ['aa', '2020-05-31 00:05:01', '2020-05-31 00:07:31'],
        ['bb','2020-05-31 00:05:01', '2020-05-31 00:06:01'],
        ['aa','2020-05-31 22:05:01', '2020-06-31 09:08:03'],
        ['cc','2020-05-31 22:10:01', '2020-06-31 09:40:01'],
        ['dd','2020-05-31 00:20:01', '2020-05-31 15:35:01']]


df_test = pd.DataFrame(data,  columns=['user_id','login', 'logout'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I need to be able to tell how much time each session spent in 4 different shifts:

night (12am to 6 am), morning (6am to 12pm), afternoon (12pm to 6pm), evening(6pm to 12am)

I was able to solve this (code below) but some session span over multiple days and if the shift starts at 10pm and ends at 9am next day, my script wont properly allocate time.

Im not sure if there is a proper algorithm for this kind of problem in python.

Here is my code:

```
shifting = df_test.copy()
# extracting day from each datetime. We will use it to dynamically create shifts for each loop iteration
shifting['day'] = shifting['login'].dt.floor("D")

# adding 4 empty columns to the data, 1 for each shift
shifting['night'] = ''
shifting['morning'] = ''
shifting['afternoon'] = ''
shifting['evening'] = ''

# writing logic to properly split time between shifts if needed
def time_in_shift(start, end, shift_start, shift_end):

    """ 
    Properly splits time between shifts if needed.
    The logic is as follows: if the user logs in before the actual the shift start time -> shift's start time takes place of the login time.
    if the user logs out after the shifts end time -> shift's end time takes place of the logout time. This logic is not perfect as sessions can span over
    multiple days. This function accounts for that by equally splitting the time in 4 if a session is longer than 24h. Need a bit more time to figure out the rest.

    Args:
    start (datetime): login timestamp.
    end (datetime): logout timestamp.
    shift_start (datetime): start time of a shift.
    shift_end (datetime): end time of a shift.
 
    Returns:
    hours spent in each shift (numeric)
    """
# first condition: if the session is longer than 24h -> split evenly between 4 shifts
    if (end - start).total_seconds()/3600 > 24:
        return (end - start).total_seconds()/3600/4
# if not -> follow the logic outlined in the description of this function        
    else:

        if start < shift_start:
            start = shift_start 
        if end > shift_end:
            end = shift_end
# calculating time spent in the session here (in hours)
        time_spent = (end-start).total_seconds()/3600

# negative hours means that no time was spent in that shift -> turn to 0
        if time_spent < 0:
            time_spent = 0

        return time_spent


# applying the time_in_shift function to each row of the connections dataset (now shifting)
for i in shifting.index:
# dynamically creating shifts for each session. Must be done because dates are always different.
    shift_start=(shifting.loc[i,'day'],
             shifting.loc[i,'day'] + timedelta(hours = 6),
             shifting.loc[i,'day'] + timedelta(hours = 12),
             shifting.loc[i,'day'] + timedelta(hours = 18))
    shift_end=  (shift_start[1],    
             shift_start[2],
             shift_start[3],
             shift_start[0] + timedelta(days=1))

# range here corresponds to 4 shifts
    for shift in range(4):

# storing time in the shift_time variable
        shift_time = time_in_shift(shifting.loc[i,'login'], shifting.loc[i,'logout'], shift_start[shift], shift_end[shift])
```

Please let me know if you know how to do this better.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you are trying to [bin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) shift hours?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['user_id', "login", "logout"], dtype="datetime64[ns]")
df["delta_hours"] = (df["logout"] - df["login"]).dt.seconds / 3600

bins = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24]
labels = ["night", "morning", "afternoon", "evening"]

df = (
        df
        .groupby(["user_id", pd.cut(df["login"].dt.hour, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)])["delta_hours"]
        .sum()
        .unstack()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()
)

print(df)

  user_id      night  morning  afternoon    evening
0      aa   0.117222      0.0        0.0  11.050556
1      bb   0.033333      0.0        0.0   0.000000
2      cc   0.016667      0.0        0.0  11.500000
3      dd  15.750000      0.0        0.0   0.000000
```